# Hudson-CI launched screen session terminates when task ends

Tags: macos, bash, scripting, hudson, gnu-screen

The main problem I'm having is to background a screen session from Hudson-CI. The shell steps are that I need to start a screen session from a script that is launched by another script. Heres' a simple test:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
myscreen.sh
```

myscreen.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dm -S myscreen pingit.sh
```

pingit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping google.com
```

If I run ./myscreen.sh I get a screen launched that runs the ping continuously without a problem.

If I run ./test.sh, the screen is never started. I'm assuming there's something basic that I'm either forgetting or not understanding, but I can't figure out what. I thought this would work.

The real reason I want to do this is to have Hudson CI launch a continuous-test script which starts as a screen session so that it can continue in the background. What I'm finding is that the screen session terminates once the task is completed in Hudson.

Any ideas on why I can't launch a persistent screen session from a grand-parent script? Or any ideas on how to deal with this?

This is on OSX 10.6, with screen built from source (so it should work the same as linux I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I did not find the following references before, but these were the links that helped me solve the problem:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/155851/run-gnu-screen-from-script
- http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Spawning+processes+from+build

There are 2 issues here - one of screen being persisted after being launched by a grand-parent process. The other that hudson terminates a session after it completes its task.

The screen problem is resolved by zombie'ing the process as follows:

```
screen -d -m -S myscreen && screen -S myscreen -X zombie qr && screen -S myscreen -X screen pingit.sh
```

The Hudson-CI problem turns out to be a bug that's easily resolved per the above link. The solution is to add BUILD_ID=something into the shell script. So if the test.sh script from above is actually the Hudson Build shell execute, then it would have to be changed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
BUILD_ID=dontkillthisprocess
myscreen.sh
```

Once both of these steps are implemented, things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your `test.sh`, I get the error message

```
./test.sh: Zeile 2: myscreen.sh: Kommando nicht gefunden.
```

i.e. *command not found*. You'll have to write `./myscreen.sh`, if the current directory is not on the path. (Is it for you? It should not.) The same is valid for the screen call.

Changing both files to

```
#!/bin/bash
./myscreen.sh
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dm -S myscreen ./pingit.sh
```

I can start my screen without any problems.

I'm on Linux (OpenSUSE) with

```
$ screen --version
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

here.

Comment: Paulo, it's not an issue with how the scripts are started. They all start fine. But it turns out that zombie'ing the process helps to some degree, per [this serverfault post](http://serverfault.com/questions/155851/run-gnu-screen-from-script). Still does not solve my problem with Hudson (or other non-login shell) :(